# SQLite prevents duplicate column names in my VIEW

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a SQLite VIEW that is the result of multiple joined tables. All my tables have an _id column as required by Android. The result has multiple columns with the same _id name, but SQLite adds ":1" and ":2" to the duplicate names so they are no longer duplicates.

If you run the below SQL you can see the resulting view has interesting column names:

```
CREATE TABLE things ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "name" TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE thing_colors ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "thing_id" INTEGER NOT NULL , "color" TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO things VALUES ("1","car");
INSERT INTO things VALUES ("2","horse");
INSERT INTO things VALUES ("3","lamp");

INSERT INTO thing_colors VALUES ("1","1","blue");
INSERT INTO thing_colors VALUES ("2","1","red");
INSERT INTO thing_colors VALUES ("3","2","brown");
INSERT INTO thing_colors VALUES ("4","3","silver");
INSERT INTO thing_colors VALUES ("5","3","gold");

CREATE VIEW things_and_colors AS SELECT * FROM things JOIN thing_colors ON things._id=thing_colors.thing_id;

SELECT * FROM things_and_colors;
```

I find these renamed column names useful but is this normal SQL behavior and is it fine for me to rely on it?

But of course this is just an example, in real life I am joining three tables and the result has about 70 columns in it, of which 3 are named _id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't select star, select the columns individually and assign an alias as needed.

Comment: Even though that means typing out 70 column names? Seems like such a pain to type them all out.

Comment: You can (and probably should) use a code generation tool to get out of actually *typing* the column names, but you certainly want to specify them explicitly, somehow.  Not doing so means you're relying too much on the coincidence of the order and names of the columns; which could certainly change as your program evolves, and anything that depends on this secondary order (the resulting columns in the view) becomes more brittle and possibly very hard to debug.

Comment: I agree that explicitly giving them names probably is a more maintainable solution. We already have about 5 views each having 70 column names aliased. Smells like a DRY violation to me.

Comment: The DRY violation would consist of avoidable redundancies in the views, i.e. creating a new view when an existing view would have sufficed. Selecting the column-names explicitly, rather than implicitly using the asterisk shorthand, has nothing whatsoever to do with DRY.

Comment: I still think this does relate to DRY. Any time you retype the same thing again you have to at least consider that possibility. For example if I add a new column to an existing table, I need to remember to recreate my view. Any time a change in one part of the code necessitates a corresponding change in another part is an indication of a DRY violation IMO. Unless, as you say, it is unavoidable. If SQL offered a way to make a view with all columns but exclude or rename some of them that would mean adding a new column to a table requires no corresponding change, and less repeating of myself.

Comment: I do like your feature request for an "everything but" column-list: `select *, -city, -state, -zip from CUSTOMERS`. That is, all columns except for city, state, zip.  But don't hold your breath. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't depend on the view renaming your columns to avoid conflicts. I don't have a copy of the standard handy so I can't quote chapter and verse but I know that PostgreSQL will say this:

```
ERROR:  column "_id" specified more than once
```

and MySQL will say this:

```
ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name '_id'
```

Those are the only databases I have handy at the moment.